# Autosize button

Tags: swift, button, constraints

In the past i've created several buttons that changes the size for iPads or iPhones, like this and works well:
[image]
Now i want to create new buttons but the size do not change.
I set Width to 400 and Height to 100 on iPad, the aspect ratio is 200:50 but the size do not change, when i change to iPhone (its still 400x100)

iPad size:
[image]

iPhone X size:
[image]
The button is huge and do not shrink as the working buttons in pic1.

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: You are unclear. You should add more images and rephrase your question

Comment: Sure, one moment.

Comment: Please add an image showing the new button's constraints

Comment: Let's do it in another way, explain me exactly what your screen distribution should look like and I'll try to do it myself

Comment: **Never ever** set width and height for buttons and labels. Once you get into changing strings from outside the storyboard, such as when localizing your app, you'll get clipped strings without noticing it. If you want to increase the hit-area for buttons, work with content / title insets instead.

Comment: I got it... i deleted the Height Equal and added aspect ratio to background. Now it works. Thanks!

Comment: @LinusGeffarth Please answer the question so that it doesn't popup in unanswered tab. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply remove the height, width and aspect ratio constraints. Some UI elements like `UIButton` and `UILabel` auto-size themselves based on their contents.

#### Also, an advice:

**Never ever** set width and height for buttons and labels. Once you get into changing strings from outside the storyboard, such as when localizing your app, you'll get clipped strings without noticing it.
If you want to increase the hit-area for buttons, work with content / title insets instead.